# Creating transition condition on Bonita BPM

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

As the title explains, been trying to figure out how to add condition to transition on Bonita, I can't seem to access the pool variables red underlines the variables i provide which belongs to the current pool, Any help please because it is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

I tried the scripts part and it worked, called the variables it needed and it was successful so am pretty much sorted out

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the "Expression type" `Comparison` to easily compare for example a process variable of type text with an expected value (constant or process parameter):

```
status == "approved"
```

If your variable is not a simple type such as boolean, string, number you will have to use a Groovy Script.